# Setting up Multicast NLB Cluster with HP 6120XG Switch

Tags: nlb, hp-procurve

How can I setup an NLB cluster across 2 blades connected via a HP 6120XG Switch?  All of the guides are for Cisco and setup static ARP entries on the switch but that is not possible on the HP Switch.
Any help would be apreciated

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1):

try the command `ip arp-mcast-replies`.  This command is found on **8210/5400/3500** and **2910** series switches, so it might be included on the **6120XG** switch.  This command allows the ARP table to learn multicast MAC address, eliminating the need to add a static ARP entry.

NOTE:  this command in only documented in the release notes so skip the guides.

Comment: Might want to take a peek here too: http://www.vcloudnine.de/flooded-network-due-hp-networking-switches-windows-nlb/